# Angle, which way to rotate to

Tags: math, computational-geometry

For a game i'm trying to calculate the angle between where i'm looking at and the position of another object in the scene. I got the angle by using the following code:

```
Vec3 out_sub;
Math.Subtract(pEnt->vOrigin, pLocalEnt->vOrigin, out_sub);
float angle = Math.DotProductAcos(out_sub, vec3LookAt);
```

This code does give me the angle between where im looking at and an object in the scene. But there's a small problem.

When i don't directly look at the object but slightly to the left of it, then it says i have to rotate 10 degrees in order to directly look at the object. Which is perfectly correct.

But, when i look slightly to the right of the object, it also says i have to rotate 10 degrees in order to look directly to the object.

The problem here is, the i have no way to tell which way to rotate to. I only know its 10 degrees. But do i have to rotate to the left or right? That's what i need to find out.

How can i figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the need to elaborate on Ignacio's answer...

In general, your question is not well-founded, since "turn left" and "turn right" only have meaning after you decide which way is "up".

The cross product of two vectors is a vector that *tells* you which way is "up".  That is, `A x B` is the "up" that you have to use if you want to turn *left* to get from `A` to `B`.  (And the magnitude of the cross product tells you how far you have to turn, more or less...)

For 3D vectors, the cross product has a z component of `x1 * y2 - y1 * x2`.  If the vectors themselves are 2D (i.e., have zero z components), then this is the only thing you have to compute to get the cross product; the x and y components of the cross product are zero.  So in 2D, if this number is positive, then "up" is the positive z direction and you have to turn left.  If this number is negative, then "up" is the negative z direction and you have to turn left while upside-down; i.e., turn right.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to perform the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) on the vectors. You can then get the direction of the rotate by the direction of the resultant vector.

Comment: But what will happen if the user looks directly in the opposite way of the object?

Comment: +1.  Note that in 2D, this reduces simply to testing whether `x1 * y2` is greater than `y1 * x2`.

Comment: Is that a Cross on the out_sub and vec3LookAt vectors?

Comment: @nightcracker: Then the answer is not defined, since you can look at the object by turning 180 degrees either direction.  Obviously you have to handle this case specially no matter what math you use.

Comment: @Nemo: I was just noting it :) But we hadn't established a definition at all, because if I am looking 10 degrees off I can move -10 or 350 degrees, so you could call that "undefined" too. (Yes, I very well know you mean the smallest absolute angle, I'm playing the devil's advocate here).